# How to make Windows font looks like Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, fonts

I have IntelliJ IDEA on my PC for java programming language.
There is a font (Consolas) and I want to make it looks like Mac font but I don't know how

[**My font**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs1o1.png)

[**Mac OS X font**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv69Z.png) (I want the same)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this issue occurs due to Windows rendering truetype differently and not up to the standard of Linux and Mac OS X. 
Take a look at these 2 applications to adjust your fonts in Windows it should make a difference - http://www.askvg.com/how-to-get-mac-os-or-linux-style-font-smoothing-in-windows/

You can also change the Anti-aliasing settings within IntelliJ IDE.

http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts/ Lists the top 10 programming fonts - Inconsolata would be a font that would give a similar feel to Mac OS X/Linux.